# Why generator iteration in list of lists doesn't work?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, iterator, generator

If we have a list of lists:

```
super_list = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
```

And we want to iterate over the inner elements we write this:

```
for sub_list in super_list:
    for item in sub_list:
        print item
```

we are going to have this:

```
# 0
# 1
# 2
# 3
# 4
# 5
# 6
# 7
# 8
# 9
```

But, when we want to use the 'generator' syntax:

```
for item in (sub_list for sub_list in super_list):
    print item
```

we are going to have this:

```
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
# [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

My question is: why? What is happening exactly in the generator?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your generator doesn't loop over any sublists; all it does is yield items from the *outer* list. The `for` loop doesn't loop over the items the generator yields, it *loops over the generator itself*.

You need to add the extra level:

```
for item in (item for sub_list in super_list for item in sub_list):
```

You can see this when you assign your generator to a variable then use `next()` on that:

```
>>> super_list = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
>>> gen = (sub_list for sub_list in super_list for item in sub_list)
>>> next(gen)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> gen = (item for sub_list in super_list for item in sub_list)
>>> next(gen)
0
>>> for item in (item for sub_list in super_list for item in sub_list):
...     print item
... 
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Comment: Should be `item` as the element yielded in the generator, not `sub_list`.

Answer (score 2):

The generator expression `(sub_list for sub_list in super_list)` will give you an iterator over the elements in `super_list`, it is essentially the same thing as `iter(super_list)`.  So if you iterate over this, it isn't any different than iterating over `super_list` directly.

If you would like to use a generator to access nested elements you can do that, but it will look something like this:

```
for item in (item for sub_list in super_list for item in sub_list):
    print item
```

Alternatively you could use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
from itertools import chain
for item in chain.from_iterable(sub_list):
    print item
```